# Hazelcast Spring Session SubZero(Kryo) EntryBackupProcessorImpl NullPointerException issue

Tags: hazelcast, spring-session, kryo

I am using `hazelcast-3.11.2` and `SubZero-0.9` as global serializer. I am trying to configure Spring Session using this [example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-hazelcast.html). When I have more than one node in cluster - I get next exception when trying to get session id:

> 2019-03-20 15:01:59.088 ERROR 13635 --- [ration.thread-3]
>   c.h.m.i.operation.EntryBackupOperation   : [x.x.x.x]:5701
>   [hazelcast-group] [3.11.2] null
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   com.hazelcast.map.AbstractEntryProcessor$EntryBackupProcessorImpl.processBackup(AbstractEntryProcessor.java:83)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperator.process(EntryOperator.java:314)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperator.operateOnKeyValueInternal(EntryOperator.java:181)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperator.operateOnKey(EntryOperator.java:166)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryBackupOperation.run(EntryBackupOperation.java:60)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.operations.Backup.run(Backup.java:158)
>     at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.call(Operation.java:170)     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:208)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:197)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:413)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:153)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:123)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:110)

My instance config looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableHazelcastHttpSession
public class HazelcastSessionConfig extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        Config config = new Config();
        SubZero.useAsGlobalSerializer(config);
        MapAttributeConfig attributeConfig = new MapAttributeConfig()
                .setName(HazelcastSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE)
                .setExtractor(PrincipalNameExtractor.class.getName());


        config.getMapConfig(HazelcastSessionRepository.DEFAULT_SESSION_MAP_NAME)
                .addMapAttributeConfig(attributeConfig)
                .addMapIndexConfig(new MapIndexConfig(
                        HazelcastSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE, false));
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    }
}
```

Removing SubZero from configuration, removes exception, so it looks like it is SubZero issue. I do use this instance as my cache provider also and hibernate second level cache, so I can not get rid off SubZero.

My thoughts were:

1. Having two different clusters: one for cache, another for session.
   Don't work for me, since I do not know how to configure Spring
   Session to use  specific hazelcast instance (pass instance name, or
   bean itself etc)
2. Specify which classes should be used with SubZero - but since I have
       plenty and new classes going to be added - this is not the best idea

Will appreciate any help.