# Hazelcast Spring Session pass node instance

Tags: hazelcast, spring-session

Trying to configure Spring Session using Hazelcast. It works okay out of the box using [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-hazelcast.html) doc - but it uses default hazelcast node. In my case I am running several nodes(those are in different clusters) on the same JVM, and I need use particular hazelcast instance to store my session. I haven't find much information, how to configure it(pass hazelcast instance name\or instance itself).

Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Next code let me to configure Spring Session to use particular node, instead of default one. Only question I have is how to configure session time to live. `hazelcastSessionRepository.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(3600)` sets only max inactive time, not time to live.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringHttpSession
public class HazelcastSessionConfig {

    @Bean//default
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setInstanceName("cache-node");
        config.getGroupConfig().setName("cluster-1");
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    }

    @Bean//Node I need to use
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastSessionInstance() {

        Config config = new Config();
        config.setInstanceName("session-node");
        config.getGroupConfig().setName("cluster-2");
        MapAttributeConfig attributeConfig = new MapAttributeConfig()
                .setName(HazelcastSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE)
                .setExtractor(PrincipalNameExtractor.class.getName());


        final MapConfig mapConfig = config.getMapConfig(HazelcastSessionRepository.DEFAULT_SESSION_MAP_NAME);
        mapConfig
                .addMapAttributeConfig(attributeConfig)
                .addMapIndexConfig(new MapIndexConfig(
                        HazelcastSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE, false));

        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    }


    @Bean//Pass node here
    public HazelcastSessionRepository sessionRepository(HazelcastInstance hazelcastSessionInstance) {
        final HazelcastSessionRepository hazelcastSessionRepository = new HazelcastSessionRepository(hazelcastSessionInstance);
        hazelcastSessionRepository.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(3600);
        return hazelcastSessionRepository;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Next code let me to configure Spring Session to use particular node, instead of default one. Only question I have is how to configure session time to live.

Have you tried to set the TTL seconds of the map config for `session-node` instance? If you ensure that the sessions are going to be stored in `cluster-2` then setting the TTL for the instance can solve your problem:

```
@Bean
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastSessionInstance() {

    Config config = new Config();
    config.setInstanceName("session-node");
    config.getGroupConfig().setName("cluster-2");
    MapAttributeConfig attributeConfig = new MapAttributeConfig()
            .setName(HazelcastSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE)
            .setExtractor(PrincipalNameExtractor.class.getName());


    final MapConfig mapConfig = config.getMapConfig(HazelcastSessionRepository.DEFAULT_SESSION_MAP_NAME);
    mapConfig
            .setTimeToLiveSeconds(300)
            .addMapAttributeConfig(attributeConfig)
            .addMapIndexConfig(new MapIndexConfig(
                    HazelcastSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE, false));

    return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Session storage is sharded across the available nodes. You can't chose which node hosts any particular session. Further, if Hazelcast needs to rebalance the shards, sessions may get moved from one node to another.

The `instance-name` parameter just dictates whether to try to find an existing connection to the cluster or whether to start a new connnection.

Perhaps the question is why do you need to control which node hosts which session?

Comment: I should have mentioned those nodes are in different clusters(groups), but running same JVM. I will have several instances of app, and two clusters. The reason I need two clusters is - one cluster will be used for distributed cache(both service and second level), another - for distributed session only.  The reason I am doing so is that for nodes in first cluster I will be using Kryo(SubZero), and I have faced issue running Kryo with distributed session. So as a workaround i was going to create separate cluster for session. For that purpose I need to tell SpringSession to use particular node.

Comment: I described my issue with Kryo and Spring Session here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55262028/hazelcast-spring-session-subzerokryo-entrybackupprocessorimpl-nullpointerexcep